# Install R packages on the fly

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Whenever I want to run a complex application in R that needs many packages and libraries, I have to install one by one all the dependencies and then re run again to see the next dependency. I am having the same problem with running a `shinydashboard` app. I wonder if there is a way the first time I am about to execute an R script, at the same time to install on the fly all the dependencies this script needs. I am running an R server on windows. Thanks!

Comment: `install.packages` has a `dependencies` parameter that defaults to a setting that should take care of this for you. Using `require` instead of `library` may be helpful if you're careful with the power. A package manager like `packrat` may be useful, as well.

Comment: What do you mean by saying: "... if you're careful with the power." ?

Comment: Sorry, that's hyperbolic. It just doesn't error out like `library`, so it's easier to program with, but also easier to ignore its failure when you shouldn't.

Comment: Do note that system dependencies will nto be loaded. Only R dependencies that are in one of your listed repos.

Comment: Am I right to assume that your "application" is not a package on CRAN (or some other semi-formal repository)? (That's the only way I can see having to install one-by-one.)

Comment: What do you mean by "run a complex application"?  Usually you only need to install everything once.  Are you building your whole setup each time you run it eg on a new virtual machine?

Comment: Yes Peter, or say another person get my app and want to run it for the first time, or the opposite, I get a totally to me knew app and want to run it for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to use `pacman`

```
library(pacman)
p_load(dplyr, reshape2) # install if needed, then load
```